# Highcharts-tooltip doesnt display date

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Iam newbie in using highcharts.

I have datepicker from and to, and getting data from json file.

The graph is shown on weekly basis.

My x-axis is weeks,so my tooltip shows week number.

I also wanted to display date in the tooltip of graph like suppose, in 1st week the date range is 31-03-2013 to 06-04-2013,when the point is on 1st week, I need to display this date in tooltip without changing the x-axis.

can anyone help through this.

Here is my code,

```
$(function () {

        $('#container').highcharts({

            title: {
                text: typeSelected + ' - Graph',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            xAxis: {
                allowDecimals : false,
                title: {
                    text: "WEEK"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var s = '<b> WEEK: '+ this.x +'</b><br/><b> '+ typeSelected +': '+ this.y +'</b>';              
                    return s;
                },
                shared: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: typeSelected
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: typeSelected,
                data: xyAxisArr,
            }]
        });

    });
    }
```

Comment: what does `typeSelected` and  `xyAxisArr` contain ?

Comment: type selected is a drop down list like complaints,visits etc where the graph is designed to show that data.xyAxisArr: x contain weeks and y contain type selected values.These are not linked to what i want.I just wanted to dispplay date selected in tooltip of the graph.

Comment: I want output something like this in link, http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/global/dateformats/   , as tooltip shows week from monday. jan7.2013

Answer (score 1):

In tooltip, you are returning `this.x`, which is timestamp. If you want date, then use for example `Highcharts.dateFormat()` to get returned date string.

Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat